# Sorted List In Generics

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the default capicity of `SortedList` in `System.Collections.Generic`? Someone told me that it's 4 but the following example shows 0 . Why?

```
        SortedList<int,string> sortedlist = new SortedList<int,string>();
        Console.WriteLine(sortedlist.Capacity);
```

Comment: can u please give me a example?

Comment: So We can't say that its default Capacity is 4.

Comment: The output from [this example](http://csharppad.com/gist/7861e2e3f85902c0ec3f) might help. Notice the capacity jumps to 4 as soon as you add an element.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) is a bit vague about this, simply saying that the list will have 'the default initial capacity'.

However, the comment in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs,86) says this:

> Constructs a new sorted list. **The sorted list is initially empty and has
>   a capacity of zero.  Upon adding the first element to the sorted list the
>   capacity is increased to _defaultCapacity**, and then increased in multiples of two as
>   required.The elements of the sorted list are ordered according to the
>   IComparable interface, which must be implemented by the keys of
>   all entries added to the sorted list.

`_defaultCapacity` is `4`.

So, to answer your question: the default is both `0` *and* `4`, depending on whether you've added an element.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is the default capacity for the generic version. It increases as you add elements, initially upping the size to 4 once you add an element. It is possible to define the initial size using the constructor `SortedList(Int32)`. Capacity will always be at least the same as Count. It can be trimmed to the exact number in `Count` using `TrimToSize()`.

[Full Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)